# Можно ли при помощи Buildozer собрать несколько классов?

Tags: python, buildozer

Мой проект состоит из нескольких классов py. Я хочу использовать Buildozer для конвертации проект в апк. Как я понял из гайдов, он конвертирует только файл main.py. Будет ли он конвертировать в пак все остальные файлы, что импортированы в main, а если нет, то как правильно импортировать их в main.py?

[image]